# Facebook share button failing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook share button on a client's site I'm working on and I'm having problems.

When you click on the share button, it takes you to facebook's site as expected. The image from the client's product is visible and correct, as well as all the description data.

However, when you share it the image switches to a type of "File not found" stock image.

We have a handlebar helper that generates a link similar to this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://path/to/product" class="icn-facebook">Share on Facebook</a>
```

It works on other projects we've done without a problem but for this site it has this error.

I've tried adding this in the header:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="url/to/image">
```

The url and everything generates properly, but it doesnt make a difference in the end result.

Is this an error on Facebook's side, our client's, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your URL with the [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) …?

Comment: Yeah actually. It came back as failing to parse the URL. However the link is perfectly valid and I can copy it into my browser and it takes me right there. I tried `encodeURIComponent()` and that even failed.

Comment: Can you show us the page in question?

Comment: @CBroe yeah, sorry but I cant. Its work related. Appreciate the help though